# Usage of "anfahren" and "überfahren"

Tags: word-usage, difference

What's the difference between *anfahren* and *überfahren*? Both mean *to run over*. Is *anfahren* used in formal registers?

Comment: please reconsider which answer is correct. The one currently marked is incomplete to say the least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **anfahren** `2,4*`: drive *into* something
2. **überfahren** `6,3*`: to drive *over* somebody (causing injury/death) or something (red light)

<sub><sup>* = `Million results using Google`</sup></sub>

Comment: This is wrong !! please look at thekeyofgb's answer

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus... that "running into" was pretty essential to answering the question. Now it is better.

Comment: *Anfahren* has much more meanings than you listed above. So either way, you give **all** of these meanings and add also the second meaning that *überfahren* has or (and that's what I suggest) you remove "start something, to drive towards a destination or having a target" as this is not of interest when comparing the similar meaning in a particular context.

Comment: The number of google hits is of no help to find the difference of meaning concerning two existing words.

Answer (score 14):

Ich meine, dass "anfahren" eher *run into* bedeutet als *run over*. "überfahren" bedeutet hingegen *run over*.

> Laut Polizeibericht hat er an der Kreuzung den Fußgänger angefahren == According to the police report, he ran into the pedestrian at the crossing
>
> Laut Polizeibericht hat er an der Kreuzung den Fußgänger überfahren == According to the police report he ran over the pedestrian at the crossing.

Note: *anfahren* can also mean "to start" (like car), jump down somebody's throat (*heftig anreden*), or to move/drive towards something (die Endposition anfahren). *Überfahren* can also mean to miss something when you're driving and drive past it (=die Ampel überfahren)

Note II: You may have noticed from my examples but *anfahren* and *überfahren" are not the same type of verbs. *Anfahren* is separable while *überfahren* is inseparable.

> Die Straßenbahn fuhr an.
>
> Ich versuchte anzufahren, aber der Motor streikte.
>
> Er fuhr die Kurve falsch an.

---

> Er überfährt uns!
>
> Ich habe heute aus Versehen eine Katze überfahren.
>
> Sie überfuhren das Stoppschild, Herr Meyers!

Comment: Not that to run into someone also means jemandem begegnen, but anfahren never means that, it always means what thekeyofgb wrote.

Comment: *jemanden anfahren* has more meanings as well. Consider *"Sie Idiot, können Sie nicht aufpassen?", fuhr er ihn an.*